# Issue with "npm install" after setting up AngularJS project with Yeoman

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gruntjs, npm, yeoman

My issue appears after (or even during) the creation of the angular project with the command:

```
yo angular
```

during the process of installing all the devDependencies from the package.json ("**npm install**" which yo angular runs) I notice that some modules are missing in the node_modules folder.

So, I downloaded after that again with the "npm install *name_of_the_module* --save-dev" (so they will  download and be included in the package.json in the devDependencies option).

But for example If I remove the **node_modules** folder and I execute the command **npm install** it will start the installation but will miss some modules, and sometimes the missing modules are different from the last run of npm install.

I don't know how to face this because I need to set up the project for the team and the first thing they will have to do is executing **npm install & bower install** (this last one works fine).

The content of package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "angular_test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "^0.7.6",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.7.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "^0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^0.8.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-filerev": "^0.2.1",
    "grunt-google-cdn": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-karma": "^0.9.0",
    "grunt-newer": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "^0.3.2",
    "grunt-svgmin": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "^2.4.0",
    "grunt-wiredep": "^1.7.0",
    "imagemin-jpegtran": "^2.0.0",
    "imagemin-pngquant": "^2.0.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "^0.2.0",
    "karma": "^0.12.24",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.1.5",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.1.4",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^0.6.0",
    "time-grunt": "^0.3.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  }
}
```

and the errors or log I get after executing npm install is:

```
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-optipng@1.0.0
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing http-signature@0.10.0
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-jpegtran@1.0.0
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-pngquant@1.0.2
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-gifsicle@1.0.0
npm ERR! EEXIST, open 'C:\Users\myself\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\78af9c6a-m-cache-lodash-2-4-1-package-tgz.lock'
File exists: C:\Users\myself\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\78af9c6a-m-cache-lodash-2-4-1-package-tgz.lock
Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\myself\Documents\PHPStorm_Workspace\angular_test
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path C:\Users\myself\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\78af9c6a-m-cache-lodash-2-4-1-package-tgz.lock
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! errno 47
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

**UPDATE**

All these issues appear because of "npm" so after researching a little bit, the creator of npm suggested to download the last version, which is only available either...

> npm install -g npm@next

or

> npm install -g npm@2.1.2 (in this case is only for the current release 2.1.2, which is the latest release)

or

- Downloading the source and copying its content where npm is installed (inside the node_modules folder where you installed node.js):
  https://www.versioneye.com/nodejs/npm/2.1.2

When I find the github discussion I will update the post with it.

Comment: Here are detailed instructions for fixing this in Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26547749/168205

Answer (score 2):

This is bug and can be fixed by update your npm version (https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6318). 
Try: npm -g install npm@next

Answer (score 1):

> File exists:
>   C:\Users\myself\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\78af9c6a-m-cache-lodash-2-4-1-package-tgz.lock
>   Move it away, and try again.

It seems like npm is resolvng from your cache, try **# npm cache clear** (for more [info](http://origin1tech.wordpress.com/2013/08/31/clearing-nodes-npm-cache/)) to make sure a package isn’t loading anything from npm’s cache.

Comment: I tried several times but that message appears even after cleaning the cache and re-run "npm install" again

Comment: mmm just to be curious try to change your package.json dependency  to 2.4.0 and do another npm install

Comment: which dependency should I change to 2.4.0?

Comment: it seems like you are havinf problems with imagemin-optipng@1.0.0, if that's not the issue locate the first depency it's not resolving and try to downgrade one minor version and see how it goes

Answer (score 1):

Most likely due to [this bug](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6309) in npm.