# Getting error while scaffolding angular app

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

I am using yeoman as a scaffolding tool and I am getting the following error . Could anyone please help me out in this. I am using windows 8 environment.

```
karma-jasmine@0.1.5 node_modules\karma-jasmine
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-optipng@1.0.0
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-jpegtran@1.0.0
npm ERR! EEXIST, open 'C:\Users\shouvik-usr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\4230a95c-m
-cache-lodash-2-4-1-package-tgz.lock'
File exists: C:\Users\shouvik-usr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\4230a95c-m-cache-lod
ash-2-4-1-package-tgz.lock
Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program File
s (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Shouvik Data\work\try
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path C:\Users\shouvik-usr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\4230a95c-m-cache-lo
dash-2-4-1-package-tgz.lock
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! errno 47
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Have you done as it says? Delete the lock file `C:\Users\shouvik-usr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\4230a95c-m
-cache-lodash-2-4-1-package-tgz.lock` (probably a leftover of a previous failure).

Comment: Yes I tried doing that as well. It doesn't help.

Comment: try running it in a shell as admin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Temporary solution

Run `npm install` manually when yeoman task is done - it's without problems then.

### Permanent solution

The better way is to update your npm tool. Open `cmd` as the admin and go into nodejs folder, on Windows it's typicaly `C:\Program Files\nodejs` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs`. Than run `npm install npm@next` and check the version by `npm -v` (you can check current version here).

If it's not possible e.g. because of permissions you can install the new npm version into another directory and then replace the old version by the new version.

Be aware of installation with `-g` flag: the default locaiton for global installation on Windows is `%APPDATA%/npm` and not nodejs installation folder - if you install it this way you have to move npm files into it.

I also recommend to backup your original npm files and in the case of failure to restore it - better save than sorry.

Comment: Updating npm per these instructions fixed it for me (i.e. running `npm install npm@next` as admin in the nodejs installation folder).  The root cause is a bug in npm prior to version 2.1.1 (see https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6238#issuecomment-57036754 for details).